# Django: 'ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported' When Trying to Run Shell

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run the python shell through the Django manage.py file like so: $ python manage.py shell --plain

I keep running into this ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/donnyknight/Desktop/djangoproj/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/donnyknight/Desktop/djangoproj/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/donnyknight/Desktop/djangoproj/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/donnyknight/Desktop/djangoproj/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/donnyknight/Desktop/djangoproj/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 77, in handle
    import readline
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyreadline.rlmain import Readline
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyreadline/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import logger, clipboard, lineeditor, modes, console
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyreadline/clipboard/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .win32_clipboard import GetClipboardText, SetClipboardText
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyreadline/clipboard/win32_clipboard.py", line 37, in <module>
    import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/wintypes.py", line 23, in <module>
    class VARIANT_BOOL(_SimpleCData):
ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported
```

I am on a mac and see that it is trying to call windows packages, but I am not sure how to configure Django to fix this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit -** 
The problem may be stemming from the readlines.py file. When trying to import it on it's own, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/donnyknight/Desktop/Django/djangotest/mysite/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import readline
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/donnyknight/Desktop/Django/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/readline.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/donnyknight/Desktop/Django/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/readline.so: file too short
```

**Edit #2 -** 
It seems like its a problem with virtualenv. Running this command outside of the virtualenv works fine.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608232/valueerror-type-v-not-supported-error-after-installing-pyreadline

Comment: @ShangWang: alright i'll give that a go if it seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645471/sqlmap-with-error-valueerror-type-v-not-supported

Comment: @SaeX: I saw that before, it doesn't really provide a solution, though.

Comment: @ShangWang: No dice, tried a different python version and am having the same problem.

Comment: Note this problem doesn't seem to be related to Django. If you open a Python shell (not through manage.py) and try to do a `import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes`, you should also see this error. Try to work from there.

Comment: @SaeX yes but why is Django even trying to use this package if it's incompatible with a mac?

Comment: Not sure what the deal is, but looks like it could be stemming from a bad install of the readline.py? Edited the main post to show the error of trying to import readline on its own. 

Don't know why i'm having an issue, am using virtualenv with a fresh python install. Figuring this out seems like it will be a little above my capabilities so think i'm going to move on. Thanks for the effort guys.